# Equality of random variables measurable w.r.t. different sigma-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm stuck trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $\tau $ be a non-negative random variable on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. We'll consider the following filtrations on the given probability space:
>
> - filtration $(\mathcal{H}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ where $\mathcal{H}_t=\sigma(\mathbb{1}_{ \{ \tau \leq u\}} : u \leq t \}$;
> - filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$, s.t. $\tau$ is not a $(\mathcal{F}_t)$-stopping time;
> - filtration $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ s.t. $\mathcal{G}_t = \mathcal{F}_t \vee \mathcal{H}_t$.
>
> Now, I have to prove that for every $\mathcal{G}_t$-measurable rv $X$ there is some $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable rv $\tilde{X}$ such that $X \mathbb{1}_{\{ \tau > t \} } = \tilde{X} \mathbb{1}_{ \{ \tau > t \} }$.

In the book I'm using, it's stated that the result follows from the (proven) fact that for every $A \in \mathcal{G}_t$, there exists $B \in \mathcal{F}_t$ s.t. $A \cap \{ \tau > t \} = B \cap \{ \tau > t \}$, but I'm not sure how to use that.

Comment: In other words... the result holds when X is two-valued. You might be able to extend it to the case when X takes a finite number of values, then when X is a step function, then when X is nonnegative, then to every X?